# ¿Qué tiene que ver "acérrimo" (aplicado a personas) con "acre"?

Tags: etimología, significado, historia, adjetivos, superlativos

Siempre me ha llamado la atención el sufijo *-érrimo/a* para construir superlativos. Aunque dicho sufijo no viene recogido en el DRAE, el [capítulo 7.4](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QukPvocyjJRvxkhH) de la Nueva Gramática se dedica a estos y otros sufijos de grado extremo, y concretamente el [epígrafe 7.4n](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=fuHKgByqxgXhPKzz).

Buscando información llegué a [esta página](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/-%C3%A9rrima,_-%C3%A9rrimo), donde se listan una serie de adjetivos recogidos en el DRAE con esta terminación. Se incluyen pulquérrimo (de *pulcro*), paupérrimo (de *pobre*), aspérrimo (de *áspero*), celebérrimo (de *célebre*), salubérrimo (de *salubre*), libérrimo (de *libre*), misérrimo (de *mísero*), nigérrimo (de *negro*), integérrimo (de *íntegro*), acérrimo (de *acre* o *agrio*) y ubérrimo (de *abundante*).

El que me llamó la atención fue:

> **[acérrimo, ma](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0OG9QQQ)**
>
> Del lat. acerrĭmus.
>
> 1. adj. sup. de acre.
> 2. adj. Muy fuerte, vigoroso o tenaz.
> 3. adj. Intransigente, fanático, extremado.

La acepción de *acre* a la que se hace referencia es esta:

> **[acre](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0aiE409)**
>
> Del lat. acer, acris. Sup. irreg. acérrimo.
>
> 1. adj. Áspero y picante al gusto y al olfato, como el sabor y el olor del ajo, del fósforo, etc.
> 2. adj. Dicho del genio o de las palabras: Áspero y desabrido.
> 3. adj. Med. Dicho del calor febril: Acompañado de una sensación como de picor.

Cuando se usan expresiones como "enemigo acérrimo" o "defensor acérrimo" se suelen usar apelando a la segunda o tercera acepción de *acérrimo*, pero **¿qué tiene que ver un carácter fuerte, vigoroso o tenaz con tener un carácter áspero o desabrido? ¿Cómo llegó a adquirir "acérrimo" dicha acepción?**

Comment: Is the relevant superlative not that of meaning 1 of _acre_? So your enemy is very unpleasant rather than very strong?

Comment: @mdewey not really. You can also be _un acérrimo defensor de la justicia_. Linking "acérrimo" with "enemy" is just an example. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: -érrimo no es un sufijo español sino latino, o sea que las palabras terminadas en -érrimo llegaron al español ya formadas, son cultismos. Por eso no aparece en el DRAE.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I learn something every day.

Comment: @mdewey no problem. I have updated the question to clarify it.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, I just learned today that "listar" is indeed a verb listed on the RAE. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Acre` es un cultismo importado del latín (*acer, acris*) en el siglo XVI. `Acérrimo` no deriva de `acre`, sino que también se importó como cultismo por la misma época, directamente del latín *acerrimus*, superlativo de *acer*.

*Acer* en latín tiene muchos más significados que los importados con `acre`:

> **ācer**    *ācris ācre* [cp. *ācrior -ius,* sp. *ācerrimus -a -um*] : agudo, cortante, acerado || penetrante; agrio; estridente; deslumbrador || agudo, vivo, sutil *(oculi; animus)* || rudo, áspero, riguroso *(hiems);* doloroso (*acris memoria,* recuerdo penoso) || ardiente, impetuoso, fogoso (*acer ad efficendum,* pronto a la acción); valiente, enérgico, infatigable; apasionado, violento, irascible; cruel, encarnizado.
>
> <sup>Diccionario Ilustrado VOX Latino-español / Español-latino</sup>

Simplemente, cuando se importó `acre`, la nueva palabra no mantuvo todos los significados de la original; y cuando se importó `acérrimo` esta mantuvo algunos significados de *acerrimus* que no tienen su contraparte en `acre`. De ahí la desconexión entre ambas.